# Parsing log files, displaying logs between specific dates

Tags: linux, shell, logging

I would like to parse a log file and to extract the lines between two specific dates ... I have read a lot of pages about this, but my problem is that my log file has a specific date type :

```
INFO - 27/04/2020 15:00:16 400 - [infoinfoinfo ] - [infoinfoinfo] - [infoinfoinfo]
```

Here is an example of a line in my log file. Only by doing greps (and I still can't figure out how), I don't see any issue to my problem ! Do you see a solution to this, looking at my date format ?

Thank you in advance !!

Comment: Not really ! I have tried but it's not the same issue I think ... always the date format problem !

Answer (score 0):

You should reformat the date to yyyy/mm/dd in order to compare them.

You can create the `log.awk` file

```
{
    # create a command that will convert the date from dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy/dd/mm
    # and apply it on third field
    cmd = "echo "$3" | sed 's-\\(.*\\)/\\(.*\\)/\\(.*\\)-\\3/\\2/\\1-'"

    # execute sed and store result in datef
    cmd | getline datef
    close(cmd)

    # filter on date
    if (datef>=datemin && datef<=datemax)
        print $0
}
```

and invoke your program this way (here, filter only on april 2020):

```
 awk -f log.awk -vdatemin=2020/04/01 -vdatemax=2020/04/30 log.log
```

---

You can also add time to you date (I did not tested this one):

```
{
    # create a command that will convert the date from dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy/dd/mm
    # and apply it on third field
    cmd = "echo "$3" | sed 's-\\(.*\\)/\\(.*\\)/\\(.*\\)-\\3/\\2/\\1-'"

    # execute sed and store result in datef
    cmd | getline datef
    close(cmd)

    datetime = datef ":" $4

    # filter on date
    if (datetime >=datemin && datetime tef<=datemax)
        print $0
}
```

and invoke your program this way:

```
 awk -f log.awk -vdatemin=2020/04/01:12:00:10 -vdatemax=2020/04/30:15:00:00 log.log
```

Comment: Thank you ! But what about the date ? ```cmd = "echo "$3" | sed \'s-\\(.*\\)/\\(.*\\)/\\(.*\\) \\(.*\\):\\(.*\\):\\(.*\\)-\\3/\\2/\\1 \\4:\\5:\\6-\'" ``` is okay to have the time too?

Comment: @maisie63. Yes, see my udpate

Comment: Thanks @Mathieu ! Have you seen the format of my date ? It's ```27/04/2020 15:00:16 400``` and between the time and the date there's a space and not a ":"...

Comment: I tried to remplace ```datetime = datef ":" $4``` by ```datetime = datef " " $4``` because of the space between my date and my time, but it's not working. I think it's because of ```-vdatemin``` and ```-vdatemax``` when I put a value such as ```2020/04/01 12:00:10``` ! The space is not recognized and I tried to add extra quotes but still not working... Any idea?

Comment: Yes, I saw it.
In `awk`, date will be in `$3`, time in `$4`. In my answer edit, I chose to glue them with a `:`. But you can do what you want.

Comment: if `datemin` has a space, define it this way: `-vdatemin="2020/04/01 10:00:00"`: add quotes: `"`

Comment: It's quit working, it's displaying the correct lines, but at the beginning the line ```awk: log.awk:4: warning: escape sequence `\'' treated as plain `'' ``` and after displaying the lines it's not exiting the script ... any idea?

Comment: @maisie63: mmm, it seems that the `\'` are not necessary and can be replaced by simple `'`

Comment: Where ? In the awk file or in the script ?

Comment: I think that the \' is necessary because when I'm trying without, it's not working ... I tried to store the data in a file, not working. I tried to display it, not working ... When I'm putting back the \' it's working again but I still have the warning ! really can't understand why I have this problem, do you?